# Extracting output value from json format using bash

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

How can I extract the value 3be847cb-48d6-ea4d-05ab-ee8ea2bd7337 shown below? I was trying to use something like awk with {'print $'}, but this doesn't work because the entire output is the first item.

Command:

```
$ curl -s --request GET http://x.y.z.10:8500/v1/kv/my-key-value
```

Output:

```
[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"w-key-value","Flags":0,"Value":"Nw==","Session":"3be847cb-48d6-ea4d-05ab-ee8ea2bd7337","CreateIndex":16,"ModifyIndex":33212}]
```

Comment: From the top of my head I can think of `<curl command> | grep -o "Session.:.[a-e0-9-]*." | cut -d '"' -f3`. Please add more info in case you need a specific answer (eg considering other formats, performance, clean code etc)

Comment: Your head must be the sharpest point. It worked!

Answer (score 2):

For extracting from json you should use jq if you can. According to authors "jq is like sed for JSON data" [(source)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

In your case it should be:

```
$ curl -s --request GET http://x.y.z.10:8500/v1/kv/my-key-value | jq -r '.Session'
```

Output will be:

```
3be847cb-48d6-ea4d-05ab-ee8ea2bd7337
```

Before you use jq you should install it on Debian and Ubuntu it will be:

```
$ sudo apt install jq
```

for other OS you should check [this site](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).